# Obtaining and storing refresh token using Authlib with flask

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, authlib, requests-oauthlib

I'm using the authlib https://github.com/lepture/authlib obtain user authentication to their data, so a daily offline scheduler can download some data on the behalf of the user.

I first register the client:

```
google = oauth.register(
    'google',
    client_id = '***',
    client_secret = '***',
    access_token_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token", 
    access_token_params = None,
    authorize_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth",
    authorize_params = None,
    api_base_url = 'https://googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/',
    client_kwargs={'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/doubleclickbidmanager'}
)
```

and at a later stage I retrieve the token using:

```
token = oauth.google.authorize_access_token()
```

when I print the token, I see that Google has not return the refresh token that I need to store on my database for offline use:

```
{'access_token': '***', 'expires_in': 3599, 'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/doubleclickbidmanager', 'token_type': 'Bearer', 'expires_at': 1591750317}
```

Can I change the way I register the client with access_type = offline in order to let Google know that I need the refresh token too? How do I get and store the refresh token?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the solution for adding `access_type` to authorization endpoint:

```
google = oauth.register(
    'google',
    # ...
    authorize_params={'access_type': 'offline'},
)
```

Use this `authorize_params` to pass extra parameters to authorize_url.

Comment: this with a combination of this and the  'prompt': 'consent' on client_kwargs, this has worked like a charm. Thank you for the quick answer and the amazing library!